# Иконки для пунктов ListView

Tags: android

В этом http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html уроке описывается как создать кастомный список. Но там одна иконка для всех пунктов. В моем приложении пунктов в списке будут достаточно много где-то 500 штук и данные будут выводиться из БД. Как в таком случае правильнее назначить каждому пункту свою иконку?

Может добавить в таблицу из БД колонку со ссылками типа R.drawable.img1.png, R.drawable.img2.png или как в таких случаях поступают?

Answer (score 2):

Сколько будет возможных иконок и от чего зависит, какую их них показать?

Если на каждую картинку уникальная иконка, то да, лучше в БД для каждой записи хранить имя файла с картинкой, и при отображении каждого элемента подгружать картинку по имени, например, c помощью [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/" + iconName + ".png").into(iconImageView);
```

Если иконок порядка десятка, и зависят они от типа отображаемого элемента, то тогда иконки удобно оставить в drawable, и при отображении выбирать нужную с помощью if/switch.

```
switch (item.getType()) {
    case TYPE_1: 
        imageView.setImage(R.drawable.icon_type_1);
        break;
    case TYPE_2: 
        imageView.setImage(R.drawable.icon_type_2);
        break;
    ....
}
```

Другой вариант -- заранее подготовить соответствие типа записи и иконки и использовать его:

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import android.support.annotation.IntegerRes;
import android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

public class IconHelper {

    public static final int TYPE_1 = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_2 = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_3 = 3;

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @IntDef({TYPE_1, TYPE_2, TYPE_3})
    public @interface ItemType {}

    private static final SparseArrayCompat<Integer> iconList = new SparseArrayCompat<>();
    static {
        iconList.put(TYPE_1, R.drawable.icon_type_1);
        iconList.put(TYPE_2, R.drawable.icon_type_1);
        iconList.put(TYPE_3, R.drawable.icon_type_1);
    }

    SparseIntArray

    public static @IntegerRes int getIconByType(@ItemType int type) {
        return iconList.get(type, R.drawable.icon_default);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`R.drawable.img1` - это `public static final int` переменная в автоматически генерируемом классе `R` которые содержит ID для ресурсов приложения всех типов, включая строки, числа, стили, размеры, картинки etc. Т.е. каждый раз при сборке проекта (читай запуске оного) эти значения могут поменяться. Т.е. нет смысла пытаться сохранять их в БД.

В вашем случае, думаю, разумнее хранить в БД путь к файлам картинок и поставлять папку с файлами картинок совместно с БД. Т.е. при отображении пунка списка вы из БД будете брать путь до картинки и отображать оную

Comment: Т.е. в бд сделать колонку с путями иконок для каждой записи и при отображении пунктов выводить соответствующую иконку из папки? Так имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Колхозник, да, всё верно

Comment: В принципе так и думал сделать. Хотелось узнать есть ли способы получше. Спасибо.